# Changing color using variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just need to change color from the array

```
var colorr = ["#008000", "#e0ffc1", "#ffc1e1", "#cc0000"];  
<span class='badge' style='background-color: colorr[0]; font-size: 25px ;'>
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Since you've hardcoded the colors in your JS file, why not hardcode them in a CSS file add use classes?

Answer (score 6):

Use jQuery (of course ;))

```
$(".badge").css('background-color', colorr[0]);
```

You will need to find a way to select you element. This example uses the class selector. You could also give it an id, and use `$("#theid")` instead.

Or use any other selector mechanism provided by jQuery, see: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: or `element.style.backgroundColor = colorr[0];` if you prefer not to use jQuery.

Comment: If i have two <span class = 'badge' and I need to change the color of only one badge, what should i do ? 

Your above code has its effect on both the badged

Comment: Another way to select a single element of `.badge` is to use `nth-child` [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/PZc8B/) Check out the demo to see. Note: This is using `CSS 3`

Comment: @Ruddy Wrong - it doesn't use CSS 3. jQuery has its own traversing engine *based* on CSS (it copied the style of it), but it works completely independently, which is why you have selectors such as `element:not(:empty)` which would never work in CSS.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Not sure why I couldn't work that out for myself lol, that's pretty dam handy to know and makes a lot more sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Ruddy You're welcome - you can also create your own selectors that use anonymous functions to find *exactly* the elements you need in your specific project.

Answer (score 4):

**simply by this :**

```
 $(".badge").css({backgroundColor: colorr[0]});
```

[Live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/dKeQ4/)

Comment: Yes.... because there's not already that answer below. All you have done is add `{}` to it, why put another answer of something that has already been posted.

Comment: @Ruddy No one is forcing you to upvote the answer. This has a live example and uses `.css()` with `backgroundColor` instead of `background-color`.

Comment: @Ruddy I guess you only know css , you should gain little bit jquery knowledge also , both works differently the ans above would have solved the problem but what if you want to give backgroundcolor and color property together from array like 

$(".badge").css('background-color', colorr[0] , 'color':colorr[0]);// wrong 

see future prospects don't stuck in solutions only 

and by the way it did not see the above code !

Comment: @h2ooooooo Oh dear, did I say anyone was forcing me to up-vote? I left a comment because there is no reason for this to be here due to someone already answering the question. I haven't down voted because its not wrong, there is just no need for it.

Comment: @user3011961 Sorry what? `I guess you only know CSS , you should gain little bit jQuery knowledge`... care to explain? That makes no sense, I have said very little about anything to do with jQuery. Not sure how you come up with I only know `CSS`.

Comment: @Ruddy i think you did not get the point both works different ?

Comment: @Ruddy If you feel this answer doesn't belong here, feel free to flag it, but all it'll get you is a declined flagging request. There's no need to be rude to people trying to help.

Comment: @Ruddy below you can find so many answers now, so comment in each answer that why you guys posted if we have one ans go ahead , and please don't  demotivate people to not answer the questions someone else would be !

Comment: @user3011961 Oh dear. You don't have to have a fit about it. Here I will make you feel better by giving you a `+1` as it is correct.

Comment: Also @h2ooooooo I fail to see where I have been rude. I was just saying that **I** think its not really needed, don't really matter anyways now as people have seem to spam the question with longer and more complicated answer.

Comment: @Ruddy you can decrease vote , doesn't make any diff to me i don't answer here for votes i answers here to help people because i take help from others in stackoverflow too ! so feel free to downvote :) thnx

Comment: @user3011961 Wow, you really are having a little fit about this aren't you. If I wanted to downvote I would have. I upvoted because the answer is **correct**. No real reason for you to continue on and im fairly certain most people come here to help other. Not for a number just below there names.

Comment: @Ruddy Lets end the discussion here,  i have so many fruitful works to do :) have a nyc day

Comment: @user3011961 Fair enough, just want to say I didn't intend to annoy you or anything like that. Meh, its early in the morning so lets just go with that. :)

Answer (score 0):

**With JS**

```
document.getelementsbyclassname('badge')[0].style.backgroundColor = colorr[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *need* to keep changing the colours from the array, you can do:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('badge');
var colorr = ["#008000", "#e0ffc1", "#ffc1e1", "#cc0000"];
var index = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    index = (index + 1) % (colorr.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = colorr[index];
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use

```
$(".badge:eq(3)").css('background-color', colorr[0]);
```

Or

```
$("span.badge:eq(3)").css('background-color', colorr[0]);
```

It will apply color to fourth span has class `.badge`

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PZc8B/2/)

Comment: It's not explained in the slightest, but this will select the fourth occurence of an element with the `badge` class. (*also, no - it'll apply color to the fourth **element**. If you have 4 `<div>`s with the `.badge` class, it'll pick that - it doesn't care about the tag*).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(colorr , function(i, item) { 
    $(".badge").css('background-color', item); 
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with `$('.badge').css('background-color', colorr[3])`? It does the exact same. You're just replacing the colour 3 times before ending up with the last one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following
Use a function in script tag

```
function load() {
        var colorr = ["#008000", "#e0ffc1", "#ffc1e1", "#cc0000"];

        var sp = document.getElementById('span1');
        sp.style.backgroundColor = colorr[0];
    }
```

And add the function load() in onload property of body tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in html and below in ts or js file

<div [style.background]="getColor(criteria)" >

```
     switch (para) {    
      case "abc": return '#7C8DFF'; 
      case "xyz": return '#5C2DFD'; 
    }
```